# How to run Rails queries over multiple date ranges (weeks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm trying to iterate over each week in the calendar year and run a query.

```
range = Date.new(2020,3,16)..Date.new(2020,3,22)
u = User.where(created_at: range).count
```

But I'd like to do this for EACH week in another range (say since the beginning of this year).

Ruby's `Date` has a `cweek` function that gives you the week number but there doesn't seem to be a way to easily get from the week number to the date range.

Anyway, not sure how helpful `cweek` will be as I need week to run Sunday -> Saturday.

Thoughts?

Comment: https://blog.0101010.com/making-date-trunc-use-a-sunday-week/

Comment: A standard week is Sunday to Saturday in the U.S. and Canada and some others. ISO 8601 says Monday through Sunday, which the rest of the world follows. We'd like to see what you tried instead of asking us for our thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Postgres and the model name is User based on your previous question.

If [this blog is to to believed](https://blog.0101010.com/making-date-trunc-use-a-sunday-week/) you can shift a date one day to get sun-sat day week.

```
User.group("(date_trunc('week', created_at::date + 1)::date - 1)")
    .count
```

If you want the to select the actual week number while you are at it you can select raw data from the database instead of using [ActiveRecord::Calculations#count](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) which is pretty limited.

```
class User
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Result] 
  #  the raw query results with the columns count, year, week
  def self.count_by_biblical_week
    connection.select_all(
      select(
        "count(*) as count",
        "date_part('year', created_at)::integer as year",
        "(date_part('week', created_at::date + 1) - 1)::integer as week"
      ).group(:week, :year) 
    )
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
results = User.where(created_at: Date.new(2020,3,16)..Date.new(2020,3,22))
              .count_by_biblical_week
results.each do |row|
  puts  [row[:year], row[:week], row[:count]].join(' | ')
end
```

Adding the year to the group avoids ambiguity if the results span multiple years.

Comment: I have some kind of sneaking suspicion that its not really this simple and that there are edge conditions at the beginning and end of year that are treated differently in ISO weeks and sat/sun. YMMV